# How do I get the height of an angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have spent more than an hour trying to achieve something fairly simple:
**Create an angular directive which can get and set the height of the current element. The same directive should have access to the window (browser) in order to get its height.**

So far, while testing, I have reached up to this (ugly) point:

```
myApp.directive("mainposter", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: false, //default is false, setting this to true has known bugs
    //scope: {},
    template: '<section class="mainposter">dummy text inside</section>',
    link: function(scope, elem/*, attrs*/) {
        /*elem.ready(function() {
            console.log("the current height is: " + this.prop("tagName"))
        })*/
        console.log("the current tagname is: " + elem.prop("tagName"))
        console.log("the current height is: " + elem.height())
    }
  }
})
```

Currently I am interested in having this executed only once on page load and not continuously like this solution: [When to get the width of an Angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275200/when-to-get-the-width-of-an-angular-directive)

The frustrated Angular newbie needs your help. Thank you

**EDIT:**
This question needs a slightly different answer because [in this forum](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb#commitcomment-8124407) they are mentioning that `replace: true` has known bug issues

Comment: What if user resize the browser like maximize?

Comment: The link method should only executed once per element which is being transformed by this directive. Is this not the case for your application?

Comment: @Mark I am sorry mark I am not sure that I understand your question. What is being transformed and is it happening only once or more times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed **jQuery** is useful for the task.

The height of the element with the settings `replace: false` is: `$(elem[0].firstChild).height()`
<sub>also `.outerHeight()` or `.innerHeight()` depending on what you want to calculate exactly</sub>

You get the height of the window like this:
`$(window).height()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elem[0].clientHeight` or `elem[0].offsetHeight` to get the height of the element.

```
link: function(scope, elem/*, attrs*/) {
        /*elem.ready(function() {
            console.log("the current height is: " + this.prop("tagName"))
        })*/
        console.log("the current tagname is: " + elem.prop("tagName"))
        console.log("the current height is: " + elem[0].clientHeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that `$(elem).height()`